# C# - .NET 4.0 - That Assembly does not allow partially trusted callers

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, c#-4.0, caspol, .net-security

When running from a network share, my application throws the following exception:

**That assembly does not allow partially trusted callers.**

My application references two DLL files:

- BitFactory.Logging.dll
- FileHelpers.dll

I'm not sure which one it is having problems with.

- `AllowPartiallyTrustedCallersAttribute`: Read up on it, but I do not have the source for either of the DLL files, so I'm not able to add the attribute to those DLL files.
- `CASPOL.EXE`: added my network share using a few variations, such as `caspol -machine -addgroup 1. -url \\netserver\netshare\* LocalIntranet` nothing seems to affect.

I've used CASPOL hack before, with .NET 3.5, however, it seems to not work with .net 4.0 now. Can anyone suggeest on how I can bypass this "Partially Trusted Caller" check?

Thanks.

Comment: Are those two assemblies in the GAC or in your application directory?

Comment: Sounds to me like policy is overridden.  Fuslogvw.exe can show you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

.NET 4.0 has [changed the default rules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee677170.aspx) for security policy.  You'll need to create or modify the `App.config` file for this application.

Code access security (as configured by `CASPOL`) is now ignored by default in .NET 4.0.  If you want to enable it you need to add the following to your `app.config` file:

```xml
<configuration>
   <runtime>
      <!-- enables legacy CAS policy for this process -->
      <NetFx40_LegacySecurityPolicy enabled="true" />
   </runtime>
</configuration>
```

You can configure .NET 4.0 to treat code from the network using `LoadFrom` as fully trusted with the following configuration item:

```xml
<configuration>
   <runtime>
      <!-- Treat assemblies from network locations as fully trusted. -->
      <!-- Caution: Do not point this loaded gun at your foot. -->
      <loadFromRemoteSources enabled="true" />
   </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I'm not using "LoadFrom" explicitly, only added references to the DLLs in question. neither of the options above seem to have any effect.

Comment: @nsr81 Is your executable strong-named?

Comment: no it wasn't. Everything is good after I signed the executable using *.snk key file.

Comment: @Jeffrey Hantin Hi, I have tried the method you guys posted above, it didn't work out for me.  I generated a key using sn.exe.  Then configure Sign the assembly for each project with this key.  At the end, it still complains that the third party assemblies (i.e. FileHelpers.dll) don't have a strong name.  Did I miss steps somewhere?  Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Candy A signed assembly cannot take a dependency on a non-signed third party assembly -- that's a compilation error with no way around it.

Comment: @Jeffrey Hantin Thanks.  I now see that the problem is the third party libraries were compiled with <= .NET 3.5 & unsigned, while my project is compiled with .NET 4.0.  Is there a way out of this at all?  If you prefer, my question is here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9743267/net-4-0-third-party-library-causing-that-assembly-does-not-allow-partially-tru  Thanks.

Comment: caspol. Seems like a capsule to get headaches